# Meter el resultado de una consulta sql en una variable con PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
<?php

    try {

    $nombre=$_GET["nombre"];
    $password=$_GET["pass"];


    $base=new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=te_la_juegas","root", "");
    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sql="select nombre, pass from usuarios where nombre= :nombre and pass= :pass";
    //--EL--POKEMON--

    $pokemon="select pokemon from usuarios where nombre= :nombre ";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);// PARA COMPROBAR QUE ESTAN EN BASE DATOS
    $eleccion=$base->prepare($pokemon);//PARA SABER EL POKEMON

    $resultado->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
    $resultado->bindValue(":pass",$password);// PARA COMPROBAR QUE ESTAN EN BASE DATOS
    $eleccion->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);//PARA SABER EL POKEMON

    $resultado->execute();
    $eleccion->execute();

    //******************************************************************

    $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();
    $inicial=mysql_fetch_row($pokemon);

    if ($numero_registro!=0) {

      if ($inicial=="charmander") {
        # code...
      }elseif ($inicial=="vulvasaur") {
        # code...
      }else {

      }

    }else {
      header("location:index.php");
    }

  } catch (Exception $e) {

    die("Error".$e->getMessage());

  }

 ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, formatea bien tu código para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: ¿Podrías al menos dedicarle un poco de esfuerzo a tu pregunta y agregar una descripción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de aportar una posible solución quiero señalar algunas cosas sobre tu código.

1. **Cuidado con un PDO mal configurado**: Para mí PDO es la mejor opción a la hora de consultar nuestra base de datos. Pero si el mismo **no está bien configurado** podría ser peligroso. Esa *buena* configuración implica que al momento de hacer la conexión establezcas el atributo `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` a `false` ... de lo contrario podrías ser víctima de **Inyección SQL**, como explico en el [punto **2** de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967).
2. **Usar rowCount no es la mejor opción para saber si hay datos**. Aunque es la forma más popular para *intentar* saber el número de filas que hay en una consulta, **rowCount no es la mejor opción para ello**. El mismo Manual de PHP dice lo siguiente:

> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` devuelve el número de filas afectadas **por
>   la última sentencia DELETE, INSERT, o UPDATE ejecutada** por el
>   correspondiente objeto PDOStatement.
>
> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement
>   asociado fue una sentencia SELECT, algunas bases de datos podrían
>   devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
>   **este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él** para aplicaciones portables.

Mucha gente parece no haber leído eso y sigue usando rowCount como si fuese la panacea.

En PDO, para saber si hay datos, **sólo tienes que preguntar por los mismos datos**, dado que el método que pide los datos devuelve `false` si no hay datos.

De modo que si haces algo como esto:

```
$datos = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll();
if ($datos) {
    // Aquí determinas si hay datos ¡no necesitas absolutamente de rowCount()!
}
```

Si de todos modos quieres contar el número de filas, usa un `SELECT COUNT(*)`, el cual te devolverá de forma **segura y real** cuántas filas hay en **esa tabla**.

Puedes ver este [interesante artículo publicado en PHP Delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count).

---

### Ahora paso a responder a tu pregunta

Para almacenar los resultados de la consulta en una variable, el procedimiento es éste:

```
 $pdo = new PDO(aquí credenciales de conexión);
 $sql = "SELECT ... INSERT ... UPDATE ...";
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(...); //Si aplica
 $stmt->bindValue(...); //Si aplica
 $stmt->execute(); 

 //Para almacenar los datos en una variable
 $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 //Leer variable con los datos
 foreach ($arrDatos as $value) {
    echo $value['una-columna-de-la-tabla'];
 }
```

**Nota:** Existen otras formas de almacenar el conjunto de resultados, los puedes consultar en el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php).

---

### Recomendación

Como decía al principio, PDO es a mi juicio la mejor opción para consultar nuestros datos.

El trabajo se facilita considerablemente cuando tenemos una clase dedicada a manejar las conexiones y enviar las consultas de forma segura. Si te interesa, puedes probar esta clase: [PHP-PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO).

---

### EJEMPLO DE CÓDIGO COMPLETO

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i6by-yq8q)**</kbd>

```
<!-- Para darle estilo a nuestros resultados en pantalla -->
<style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table,th,td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<?php

/*Este requiere es propio de phpfiddle, a no usar en nuestro programa*/
require "util/public_db_info.php";

/*
    *Crear objeto conexión con las credenciales
    *Cambiar los valores por los nuestros
*/
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
/*
    *Esta variable se usa para verificar si ocurrió algún error 
    *durante la ejecución del código
    *Escribiremos un código totalmente controlado
*/
$bolError=false;

/*
    *PRUEBA: Esto es para mostrar los arrays ordenados, 
    *no tendrá importancia para nuestro programa final, 
    *podemos quitarlo, junto con el </pre> del final
*/
echo "<pre>";

/*Empezamos... iré indicando los diferentes controles que se hacen*/

/*1. Verificamos que el objeto $pdo no sea nulo*/
if ($pdo){

    $strSQL="SELECT * FROM actor_20171002 WHERE actor_sexo=? and actor_id > ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($strSQL);

    /*
        *Estamos aquí ante un aspecto interesante de PDO
        *podemos prescindir de bind_param o de bind_value
        *y pasar los parámetros mediante un array ($arrParams) en el execute
        *IMPORTANTE: Los valores deben estar en el orden en que aparecen en $strSQL
        *en este caso el 1er valor debe ser el filtro para actor_sexo 
        *y el segundo el filtro para actor_id
    */
    $arrParams=array('F',5);
    $stmt ->execute($arrParams);

    /*
        *Si no se esperan demasiados datos, podemos usar fetchAll
        *para obtenerlos todos de una vez en una variable
        *si se esperan muchos datos el Manual recomienda iniciar un puntero con fetch
        *y luego ir recorriendo dicho puntero para leer los valores
        *Aquí, $arrDatos será un array asociativo con todo el resultado
    */
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*2. Verificamos los datos obtenidos*/

    /*
        *En PDO nosotros podemos actuar sobre los mismos datos
        *para hacer verificaciones...
        *por ejemplo aquí, podemos usar $arrDatos para verificar si hay resultados
        *y haciendo count($arrDatos) sabemos cuántos registros hay
    */
    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        echo "SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS\n";

        /*
            *PRUEBA: La línea siguiente es sólo para prueba
            *Podría no ser útil en nuestro programa final
        */
        print_r($arrDatos);    

        /*
            *Vamos a usar una forma de presentar los datos
            *la cual puede variar según la necesidad del programador
            *he optado por presentarlos en una tabla
            *se pueden presentar sin tabla, en un formulario, o donde queramos
            *para escribir código "limpio" (sin echo por todas partes)
            *usaremos una variable $tablaHTML a la cual le iremos agregando todo el contenido
        */
        $tablaHTML='<table>';
        $tablaHTML.="<th>ID</th>
                     <th>Nombre</th>
                     <th>Apellido</th>";

        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            $intId=$row["actor_id"];
            $strNombre=$row["actor_nombre"];
            $strApellido=$row["actor_apellido"];
            $tablaHTML.="<tr>";
            $tablaHTML.="<td>$intId</td>"; 
            $tablaHTML.="<td>$strNombre</td>"; 
            $tablaHTML.="<td>$strApellido</td>"; 
            $tablaHTML.="</tr>";
        }

        $tablaHTML.="</table>";
        echo $tablaHTML;

        /*Aquí si se desea se puede cerrar $stmt... en PDO no es necesario*/

    } else {

        /*
            *Este bloque se ejecutará cuando $arrDatos sea false
            *lo cual indicará que hubo un fallo en el $stmt,
            *por eso usamos errorInfo() del $stmt para encontrar el motivo del fallo
            *la variable $bolError declarada más arriba será establecida a true
            *y crearemos un mensaje de error
        */
        $bolError=true;
        $strMensaje="Error en la consulta: ".$stmt->errorInfo()[2];

    }

    /*Por estar en phpfiddle cerrarmos $pdo, en nuestra aplicación no es obligatorio*/
    $pdo = null;

    }else{

        /*
            *Este bloque se ejecutará cuando $pdo sea nulo
            *la variable $bolError declarada más arriba será establecida a true
            *y crearemos un mensaje de error
        */              
        $bolError=true;
        $strMensaje="La conexión  es  nula. Verifique sus credenciales o la base de datos";

    }

    /*
        *Informar sobre algún error:
        *Este bloque evalúa la variable $bolError
        *e informa sobre el error ocurrido, que se encontrará en $strMensaje
    */
if ($bolError)
{
    print_r($strMensaje);
}

/*Cerramos nuestro pre... útil sólo para nuestras pruebas :)*/
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**Resultado**:

El print_r de prueba arroja esto:

```
SE ENCONTRARON  2 REGISTROS
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [actor_id] => 6
            [actor_nombre] => Jennifer
            [actor_apellido] => Jones
            [actor_sexo] => F
            [last_update] => 2017-10-23 10:08:02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [actor_id] => 7
            [actor_nombre] => Holly
            [actor_apellido] => Hunter
            [actor_sexo] => F
            [last_update] => 2017-10-23 10:08:02
        )

)
```

Y la tabla que generamos con los datos es esta:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th>Apellido</th>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Jennifer</td>
    <td>Jones</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Holly</td>
    <td>Hunter</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```